# (Starter. Stuck on this point) generated Rails project : missing the config/routes.rb file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Following [this article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) everything works but I'm stuck on routing welcome index page as this mentioned file is missing. [image]

please mention workaround or if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Try not to post screenshots. And learning Ubuntu is easier than trying to code Rails on Windows, by a mile...)

You are in `assets/config`. Look in `Blog\config`.